# Having trouble with MusicKit sample app provided by Apple

Tags: swift, ios11, xcode9-beta, swift4, apple-musickit

I am trying to build "Adding Content to Apple Music”, Music Kit sample app provided by Apple, on Xcode 9 beta 3. However I am having 4 errors like this : three “Ambiguous use of 'play()’” errors and one “Ambiguous use of 'pause()’”

Please tell me how to fix this if you already solved this problem.

```
func beginPlayback(itemCollection: MPMediaItemCollection) {
    musicPlayerController.setQueue(with: itemCollection)

    //Ambiguous use of 'play()’
    musicPlayerController.play()
}

func beginPlayback(itemID: String) {
    musicPlayerController.setQueue(with: [itemID])

    //Ambiguous use of 'play()’
    musicPlayerController.play()
}

// MARK: Playback Control Methods

func togglePlayPause() {
    if musicPlayerController.playbackState == .playing {

        //Ambiguous use of 'pause()’
        musicPlayerController.pause()
    } else {

        //Ambiguous use of 'play()’
        musicPlayerController.play()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a similar question in the Apple's Dev Forums:

[MPMusicPlayerController Swift4 - Ambiguous Use of Play](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/82284)

According to an entry writing a fix to work around the issue, you need to change this line in MusicPlayerManager.swift:

```
let musicPlayerController = MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer
```

(`musicPlayerController`'s type becomes `MPMusicPlayerController & MPSystemMusicPlayerController` with this code.)

To:

```
let musicPlayerController: MPMusicPlayerController = MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer
```

(`musicPlayerController` is explicitly annotated as `MPMusicPlayerController`.)

---

In my opinion this is a bug of Swift related to [SE-0156 Class and Subtype existentials](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0156-subclass-existentials.md) and you should better send a bug report to [Apple](http://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/) or [swift.org](https://bugs.swift.org/).