# Ambiguous use of play of MPMusicPlayerController in iOS11, swift4

Tags: ios11, xcode9-beta, swift4

I'm running the Apple **iOS11** example [Adding Content to Apple Music](https://developer.apple.com/musickit/) on Xcode `Version 9.0 beta 3 (9M174d)`.

I get a `Ambiguous use of 'play()` in

```
/adding-content-to-apple-music/AppleMusicSample/Controllers/MusicPlayerManager.swift:78:9: Ambiguous use of 'play()'
```

The [suggested solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35658334/how-do-i-resolve-ambiguous-use-of-compile-error-with-swift-selector-syntax/35658335?noredirect=1#comment77147060_35658335) to explicitly define the selector in order to avoid the ambiguity like:

```
let play = #selector(musicPlayerController.play)
```

did not work in this case.

The `MPMusicPlayerController` instance in the `MusicPlayerManager` class is defined as

```
let musicPlayerController = MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer
```

and then referred like

```
func beginPlayback(itemID: String) {
        musicPlayerController.setQueue(with: [itemID])

        musicPlayerController.play()
    }
```

I have put the code for the `MusicPlayerManager` class [here](https://gist.github.com/loretoparisi/67bdd21d29c1a33bd6bb784b1e44ac98).

Comment: Please check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45080188/6541007).

Comment: @OOPer thank you! That's crazy. It is just that cast/annotation, sort of :D

Comment: Please thank who first posted the workaround on the web. Sharing the developers' experience is really a great thing.

Comment: @OOPer can you reply as answer so I will accept? Thank you!

Comment: @OOPer btw here another: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45101444/swiftdeferrednsdictionary-objectforkeynotnull-in-ios11-and-swift4

Comment: Maybe this question should be marked as duplicate with the link above. I'll take some time to check your another.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Having trouble with MusicKit sample app provided by Apple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45080188/having-trouble-with-musickit-sample-app-provided-by-apple)

Comment: Voted to close as a duplicate, but your description of the problem is excellent (you provide just the info needed to reproduce the problem minimally) so also upvoted. :)

Comment: I should also mention, it wouldn't hurt to file a bug with Apple on this. The more the merrier, as you probably know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write

```
    (musicPlayerController as MPMediaPlayback).play()
```