# Swift unrecognized selector of ObjC Category

Tags: ios11, xcode9-beta, swift4

I get a `SwiftDeferredNSDictionaryVs11AnyHashableP__ objectForKeyNotNull:`

```
2017-07-14 12:52:58.138873+0200 Adding-Content-to-Apple-Music[1954:511529] -[_TtGCs26_SwiftDeferredNSDictionaryVs11AnyHashableP__ objectForKeyNotNull:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c02239c0
```

for a object defined in a swift `Dictionary`

```
let apiOptions:Dictionary<String,Any> = [
            "options.push.enabled": false,
            "options.debuglevel": 4,
            ]
```

that I pass to a `Objective-C` library, that does like

```
if ([options objectForKeyNotNull:@"options.push.enabled"]) {
        pushEnabled = [[options objectForKey:@"options.push.enabled"] boolValue];
    }
    if ([options objectForKeyNotNull:@"options.debuglevel"]) {
        debugLevel = [[options objectForKey:@"options.debuglevel"] intValue];
    }
```

In the stack trace I have like

```
 0x1033b1da4 <+316>:  ldr    x20, #0xa1074             ; "objectForKeyNotNull:"
    0x1033b1da8 <+320>:  adr    x2, #0x7f718              ; @"options.push.enabled"
    0x1033b1dac <+324>:  nop    
    0x1033b1db0 <+328>:  mov    x1, x20
    0x1033b1db4 <+332>:  bl     0x1033f91f0               ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
    0x1033b1db8 <+336>:  mov    x29, x29
    0x1033b1dbc <+340>:  bl     0x1033f9238               ; symbol stub for: objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue
    0x1033b1dc0 <+344>:  mov    x21, x0
```

so it seems that the `options` object, defined in `swift` as a `Dictionary` has no selector `objectForKeyNotNull`.

**[UPDATE]**

It seems that I cannot load ObjC categories like the `objectForKeyNotNull` here:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSDictionary (MXMExtensions)
- (id)objectForKeyNotNull:(id)aKey;
@end

@interface NSData (EOUtil)
- (NSData*)dataByHmacSHA1EncryptingWithKey:(NSData*)key;
@end
```

even if it has its public header defined.

The same happens with another category:

```
2017-07-14 15:10:21.059117+0200 Adding-Content-to-Apple-Music[2075:560878] +[UIDevice platformString]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1b13b1b98
```

that it is

```
@implementation UIDevice (Hardware)
//...
+ (NSString *)platformString {
//...
}
```

In a Xcode/ObjC project I would normally set the **Other Linker Flags** to `-ObjC`, but in a Xcode/Swift project with a ObjC Framework linked, this seems not to work properly.

Comment: Testing with a simplified project and a static library with category, `-ObjC` flag works as expected. Have you tried `-all_load`?

Comment: @OOPer using -force_all will cause the app to crash. Going to try again -ObjC. Infact it should work!

Comment: `-all_load` appears only in old Apple documents and should not be needed in current build tools, just was little hope. One possibility is that the framework may be built without `-ObjC` but I cannot confirm. As you say `-ObjC` should work in this sort of issue.